# rakefile aborted don't know how to build task gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, rake, rakefile

I'm trying to install a program using Ruby.
But now I'm stuck at this error:

> rake file aborted. Don't know how to build task gems

Could someone please help me?

Rake file looks like this:

```
# Add your own tasks in files placed in lib/tasks ending in .rake,
# for example lib/tasks/capistrano.rake, and they will automatically be available to Rake.

require File.expand_path('../config/application', __FILE__)
require 'rake'

require 'rake/testtask'
require 'rdoc/task'
#require 'tasks/rails'

SkWeb::Application.load_tasks
```

Comment: Can you please paste the error here ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to require file

```
Dir.glob('lib/tasks/*.rake').each { |r| load r}
```

Your code will be

```
# Add your own tasks in files placed in lib/tasks ending in .rake,
# for example lib/tasks/capistrano.rake, and they will automatically be available to Rake.

require File.expand_path('../config/application', __FILE__)
require 'rake'
Dir.glob('lib/tasks/*.rake').each { |r| load r} 
require 'rake/testtask'
require 'rdoc/task'
#require 'tasks/rails'

SkWeb::Application.load_tasks
```